# Query database with period in name on a linked SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I need to query a database on a linked server, and unfortunately the database name contains a period.

This fails;

```
select top 10 * 
FROM [LINKED_SERVER].[DATABASE_NAME.1].dbo.[TABLE_NAME]
```

with this error:

> *OLE DB error trace [Non-interface error:  OLE DB provider unable to process object, since the object has no columnsProviderName='SQLOLEDB', Query="DATABASE_NAME.1"."dbo"."TABLE_NAME"'].
>
>   Msg 7357, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
>
>   Could not process object '"DATABASE_NAME.1"."dbo"."TABLE_NAME"'. The OLE DB provider 'SQLOLEDB' indicates that the object has no columns.*

Connecting to the same linked server without a period in the database name works;

```
select top 10 * 
FROM [LINKED_SERVER].[DATABASE_NAME].dbo.[TABLE_NAME]
```

As there are many references to the existing database name out of my control, I hope to find a solution that avoids re-naming the database permanently.

I would like to be able to create a synonym or some other alias, or find some other way to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

Periods in database names accessed via linked servers are perfectly acceptable when escaped with brackets [] - the error your getting must be something else.

I can confirm this on my test rig:

[image: http://www.heavencore.co.uk/filehub/uploaded/LinkedServerWithPeriod.jpg]

**One thought, your using the old `SQLOLEDB` provider for your linked server, have you tried using `SQLNCLI10` instead?**

Answer (score -2):

Avoid periods in identifiers,

e.g. in SSMS

```
sp_help [sales.order]
```

will not work, even with brackets

Comment: `sp_help` doesn't work with databases at all, it only works on database _objects_: `The object 'AnyDatabaseName' does not exist in database 'master' or is invalid for this operation.`